# Bluegiga BLED112 Bluetooth dongle disconnect

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to use a BLED112 USD Bluetoot 4.0 dongle from Bluegiga.

The dongle works OK under Windows 8, so I have no reason to think that there is a hardware issue.

If I plug it in under Ubunut 13.04 "raring" (kernel 3.8.0-20), I get this:

```
[ 5755.444220] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[ 5755.984120] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 43
[ 5756.524111] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 44 using uhci_hcd
[ 5756.698098] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2458, idProduct=0001
[ 5756.698102] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5756.698104] usb 3-1: Product: Low Energy Dongle
[ 5756.698106] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Bluegiga
[ 5756.698108] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1
[ 5756.706137] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[ 5757.224143] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 44
[ 5757.744071] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 45 using uhci_hcd
[ 5757.912164] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2458, idProduct=0001
[ 5757.912175] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5757.912182] usb 3-1: Product: Low Energy Dongle
[ 5757.912188] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Bluegiga
[ 5757.912194] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1
[ 5757.920274] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[ 5758.464106] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 45
[ 5758.988078] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 46 using uhci_hcd
[ 5759.160089] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2458, idProduct=0001
[ 5759.160100] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5759.160107] usb 3-1: Product: Low Energy Dongle
[ 5759.160113] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Bluegiga
[ 5759.160119] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1
[ 5759.168192] cdc_acm 3-1:1.0: ttyACM3: USB ACM device
[ 5759.704175] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 46
[ 5760.220064] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 47 using uhci_hcd
[ 5760.592121] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2458, idProduct=0001
[ 5760.592126] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5760.592128] usb 3-1: Product: Low Energy Dongle
[ 5760.592130] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Bluegiga
[ 5760.592132] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 1
```

The kernel recognizes the dongle, just to get a disconnect event a few seconds later.

I could reproduce it on multiple machines, and with a 3.5.0 kernel too.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

Modem-manager was tryingto to issue commands to the dongle wich reset itself in turn.

The solution was to add an udev rule to ignore that device (and also to create a symlink for conveniently mapping it under wine ;) ):

```
# BLuegiga BLED112
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2458", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1", SYMLINK="bluegiga/bled112"
```

I wrote an article on the whole story: http://tlfabian.blogspot.hu/2013/05/programming-bluegiga-ble112-bluetooth.html